# HTML section in Joomla messing up rest of site

Tags: html, joomla

With the help from Nix in here, I have a section which I wanna put on a Joomla page. Problem is, when I put in the section, it messes up the entire website, even though the code is in an editor in Joomla, and not connected to the rest of the site. Any idea why? The section code can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/GRf9v/222/

```
<section>
<style type="text/css">
section {
background: #A8DBFF;
border-radius: 4px;
width: 275px; height: 300px;
margin:5px;
padding: 10px;
border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;
float: left;
position: relative;
display: inline;
}
div {
background: #fff;
border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;
border-radius: 4px;
margin-left: -15px;
padding:5px;
} 

o { 
background: orange; 
margin-left: 15px;
border-radius: 2px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
}

ul { list-style: disc; margin: 5px 0; padding: 0 15px; }​
</style>
<div>
    <o>Resultater&nbsp</o>&nbspmed mennesker
</div>
<ul>
    <li>Banan</li>
    <li>Jordbær</li>
    <li>Æble</li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sem nibh, tincidunt id         vulputate quis, feugiat venenatis eros. Aliquam turpis ibh</p>
</section>​
```

Comment: Does making your selector more specific than `section` solve the problem?

Comment: According to the 2 answers I got below, it was because the rest of the page got was affected på the CSS in the section. Got it solved - thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a `class` or `id` to your section to make it specific like so:

**HTML:**

```
<section class="section"></section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.section {

}
.section div {

} 
.section o { 

}
.section ul {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will still affect CSS of the whole page. Try putting `ID` in your section and edit your css:

```
<section id="my_section">
<style type="text/css">

#my_section {
background: #A8DBFF;
border-radius: 4px;
width: 275px; height: 300px;
margin:5px;
padding: 10px;
border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;
float: left;
position: relative;
display: inline;
}
#my_section div {
background: #fff;
border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;
border-radius: 4px;
margin-left: -15px;
padding:5px;
} 

#my_section o { 
background: orange; 
margin-left: 15px;
border-radius: 2px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was probably me who got it wrong, but putting # in front of each of my_section in the css, didn't work. Thanks for the answer, though! I'm not very good at understanding HTML and CSS yet, so I probably just did something wrong with your suggestion :)